# Intents for EditText LongPress

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, long-press

i want my application to be seen when a user long presses on edit text to copy or paste.
or clicks on copy or paste.

i tried with different intents like

ACTION_PASTE ,
ACTION_EDIT

But none are working for me !!

Please help me out
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to automatically appear in the action mode or context menu that appears when the user selects text in an `EditText` for other applications.

For your *own* `EditText` widgets, you can [use `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29) to add items to the standard action mode on API Level 11+.