# What are different intent actions and categories in intent-filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

Please can any one list what are the different Android actions and categories can be used in intent-filter of Android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Since they can be arbitrary strings, there are an infinite number of them. That is too many to list here.

You can find various standard actions and categories in the SDK documentation, such as on [the `Intent` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Just understand that what you see on the `Intent` class is not even all the ones in the Android framework, let alone all the other ones defined outside of Android itself by app developers.

Comment: is there any to access the clipboards of other apps?

Comment: @kdubey007: Your comment has nothing to do with my answer or your original question. Stack Overflow answers are not chat threads. If you have unrelated questions, ask another question using the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: sorry, actually my issues was I want to allow my activity to be opened when we long press any text.for example when we long press a text it gives options like copy, paste, cut. I want my activity name with them.I would be thankful if you can help.

Comment: @kdubey007: That is not possible. Your real question is a duplicate of [this question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24433399/115145).